# Is it possible in R that by adding two dataframe we get the result even if other value for same type is not there?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes with same number of column but row count differs.
X
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccPpB.png)

y
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md2FP.png)

Now when i am try to subtract y[,c(1,2)]-x[,c(4,3)] getting error
Error in Ops.data.frame(y[, c(1, 2)], x[, c(4, 3)]) :
‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
i figured out that this is due to the fact that some of the type and wire are missing from x

So my objective is that can code assume the corresponding value as 0 against missing type and wire in x dataframe and return the result as y-0=y

Answer (score 0):

You are subsetting your data.frames by column. When subsetting using square brackets, the values before the comma are for rows. The values after the comma are columns. Your `y[, c(1:2] - x[, c(3:4]` is trying to subtract columns 3 and 4 in y from columns 1 and 2 in x. Since the columns are different lengths, it fails.

Comment: Is it possible to write a code which can add the type,wire with corresponding value 0 in x which are available in y . For example type B and wire wifi is available in y but not in x and want to add a row with type B, wire Wifi, a=0, b=0 similarly for other types and wire. I know this can be done by writing a separate code just for that entry but my objective here is to automatically detect the missing row in x and then add them so it will be easy to do the operation like addition or subtraction.

Comment: @Uttam This sounds like either a different question or details that need to be added to your question to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Ben, If you see y it has row where type is B, wire is WiFi and corresponding column has some values but in x dataframe it is missing. So what I m trying to do is to write a code that automatically detects like which site is missing with wire "Land" or "WiFi" and eventually adds them in x dataframe with corresponding value 0.

Comment: to fill the x with the missing type and wire i have put the below logic in function but it is not working.

Comment: as code is big for other types so adding only till type D which is missing as well.   Missadd<-function(z){
  z$TypeWire<-paste0(z$Type, z$Wire)
if(all(z$TypeWire != "BLand")){
   z <- rbind(z, newrow<-c("B","Land",0,0,"BLand"))
  }else if(all(z$TypeWire != "BWiFi")){
    z <- rbind(z, newrow<-c("B","WiFi",0,0,"BWiFi"))
  }else if(all(z$TypeWire != "DLand")){
     z <- rbind(z, newrow<-c("D","Land",0,0,"DLand"))
   }else (
    z <- rbind(z, newrow<-c("D","WiFi",0,0,"DWiFi"))
   }
}

Comment: Called dataframe x in above created function.
Check=Missadd(x)
And the output is below where only BWiFi is added but other missing type’s not
  Type Wire x n SiteWire 
1 A Land 20331 24 ALand
2 A WiFi 489 2 AWiFi
3 B Land 4292 4 BLand
4 C Land 2408 6 CLand
5 C WiFi 1930 1 CWiFi
6 D Land 151 1 DLand
7 O Land 8150 22 OLand
8 B WiFi 0 0 BWiFi